# How to display Object specific text in a Java GUI

Tags: java

I'm writing a records program for school, and need to display certain Object specific text data in my GUI.
For example - a patient's ID number which is already generated beforehand.
Can a jtextfield be used to do this, or only to input text?

Comment: Yes it can be used. If it's not meant to be editable call ```tf.setEditable(false)``` . A ```JLabel``` could also be used and might be better

Comment: [Here is a list of your options.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html)  Most component classes start with a capital `J`.  Feel free to click on some of them to learn more about them.